# Why did the stranger do this in Blood Conscious?

Tags: plot-explanation, blood-conscious

In the movie **Blood Conscious**, why did the stranger (Nick Damici, the armed white man) kill himself at the end?

Comment: Thanks, @iandotkelly, I don't have enough reputation to create tags.